# Reset Style Sheet with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my website I use twitter bootstrap. Is it necessary to include reset.css with my site? Is it included in bootstrap.css file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With Bootstrap 2, the old reset block has been dropped in favor of [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), that also powers the HTML5 Boilerplate. Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards and it precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Comment: thanks god we are finally burrying the hierarchy ruiner reset concept into the history! always used a technique like normalize.css.

Answer (score 43):

`normalize.css` is included at the beginning of the `bootstrap.css` file, so you don't need to have another one.

Comment: (( The one included is actually based on Eric Meyer's CSS reset :-) [See Twitter's blog post](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/bootstrap-twitter)  ))

Comment: As of 7-11-2014, Bootstrap uses Normalize.css. From http://getbootstrap.com/css/: "For improved cross-browser rendering, we use Normalize.css, a project by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal."

Comment: Keep in mind that normalize.css is massively different from reset.css. For example, ul, ol, and li may still produce bullet points, margins, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note to this. Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 runs [Normalize.css,](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) instead of reset. (but they have kept the name as reset.css for some odd reason :D )

Comment: so are you saying that it would be good to have a reset css too. I am confused.

Comment: No you don't need to add a reset as well.. unless you want one :P