# Do i have to use a reset css with bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, css-reset

This question has never been asked before in here, though i didn't find a relevant answer for it on google too.

Reset CSS files are used widely with so many Frameworks, but bootstrap does not come with one, so do I have to add it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9853206/771578

Comment: It's included, so you don't need to worry about that.